# Custom CheckBox menu item ActionBar not work

Tags: android

i have problem with styling Custom CheckBox Menu Item ActionBar. I have implemented, but It's not styled.

[image]

I want to changed with resource this

**if checkbox is checked**

[image]

**if checkbox is not  checked**

[image]

this is my menu item Action Bar.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.tracking.bus.maps.SingleViewMapsActivity" >

        <item
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_alarm"
        android:title="@string/actionbar_alarm"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

        <item
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_interval"
        android:title="@string/actionbar_interval"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

        <item
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_log_track"
        android:title="@string/actionbar_log_track"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

style Action Bar

```
    <style name="Theme.Myab" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_myab</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Myab</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Myab</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Myab</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Myab</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Myab</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_myab</item>
        <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_myab</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Myab</item>
        <item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/DropDownItem.Myab</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem.Myab</item>        
        <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/customCheckBoxStyle.Myab</item>
        <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Myab.Widget</item>   
    </style>

   <!-- style checkbox -->      
  <style name="customCheckBoxStyle.Myab" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/custom_checkbox_design</item>
    </style>
```

**custom_checkbox_design.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>     
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     
         <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/alram_on" />
         <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/alram_off" />     
    </selector>
```

so how to solve it ? thanks sorry for my english

Answer (score 2):

First things, `android:checkboxStyle` should run on device with API 11 or later.

Try set your checkbox selector like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:enterFadeDuration="300">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked"></item>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked"></item> <!--default state, unchecked-->
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got same issue,  I have figured this out tricky way. See below:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.webview_menu, menu);
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.unfavorite);
        favorite = false;
return true; }
```

On optionitemselected:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.favoriteItem:
                if(favourite){
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.unfavorite);
                    favourite = false;
                } else {
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.favorite);
                    favourite = true;
                }
                new FavoriteTask(favourite).execute();
                return  true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

This was easiest way to implement the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the java file, you have to set the icon programmatically. If your selector file and menu files are correct, the change of the state of the checkbox will be reflected on the checkbox icon automatically.

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);//insert the name of the menu file
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item).getActionView();//find the checkbox, in your case R.id.actionbar_alarm
    checkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.star);//the name of your selector file custom_checkbox_design.xml in your case


    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            //add the action of your checkbox
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```